# How can we add some prefix in file field in CLLE program?

Tags: addition, ibm-midrange, rpgle

We use PREFIX keyword in RPGLE program to add some prefix in file field like below.

```
FTESTPF  i f  e  k disk    Prefix(@)
```

Is there any alternative of PREFIX keyword in CLLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CL is not intended as a database language, so it doesn't support as many features as RPG or other business languages. There shouldn't be a need for a "prefix" in CL.

However, the OPNID() parameter of DCLF provides a basic "prefix" capability.